# Beginners GUI slideshow code not working (might be problem with loop or button, unsure)

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating a picture-slideshow which will have one button to switch to the next image and is supposed to cycle through them.

Iv tried Switching to case statement and nested boolean statements for my loop.

```
/*
 *
 */


import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SlideShow implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel picture;
    JLabel label, picture1;
    JButton button;
    JPanel contentPane;
    int x = 0;




    public SlideShow() {
        /* Create and set up the frame */
        frame = new JFrame("SlideShow");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /* Create a content pane with a BoxLayout and empty borders */
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        /* Create a label that shows a die face */
        picture1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        picture1.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        picture1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 10, 0));
        contentPane.add(picture1);

        button = new JButton("Next photo");
        button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button);

        /* Add content pane to frame */
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        /* Size and then display the frame. */
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }








    //ActionPerformed//
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String[] array = {
            "attachment_142650738.jpg", // 0
            "attachment_142650739.jpg", // 1
            "attachment_142650741.jpg", // 2
            "attachment_142650742.jpg" // 3     
        };


        x += 0;
        if (x == 1) {
            picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        } else if (x == 2) {
            picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        } else if (x == 3) {
            picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        } else if (x == 4) {
            picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        } else if (x == 5) {
            x = 0;
            picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("attachment_142650738.jpg"));
        }


    }




    //GUI//
    private static void runGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        SlideShow ok = new SlideShow();


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
           run from an event-dispatching thread */
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There are no errors currently but the button has no outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize member `x` of class `SlideShow` to zero (0) - which is unnecessary as it is implicitly initialized thus anyway.

In method `actionPerformed` you have this line of code

```
x += 0;
```

You are not changing the value of `x`. Hence it remains zero and therefore none of your conditional statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

You code is already pretty good, but you will have to make a few changes. At first, you don't need the if/else statements, you can just access the array. Then I would also increase the value of x and I also made some tiny changes so that the slideshow will start from the beginning when you're at the end. Of course you will need to replace my image array with yours.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SlideShow implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel picture;
    JLabel label, picture1;
    JButton button;
    JPanel contentPane;
    int x = 0;

    String[] array = {
            "D://image1.jpg",
            "D://image2.jpg",
            "D://image3.gif"
    };

    public SlideShow() {
        /* Create and set up the frame */
        frame = new JFrame("SlideShow");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /* Create a content pane with a BoxLayout and empty borders */
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        /* Create a label that shows a die face */
        picture1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(array[x]));
        picture1.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        picture1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 10, 0));
        contentPane.add(picture1);

        button = new JButton("Next photo");
        button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button);

        /* Add content pane to frame */
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        /* Size and then display the frame. */
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ActionPerformed//
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        x++;
        if (x >= array.length) {
            x = 0;
        }

        picture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(array[x]));
    }

    // GUI//
    private static void runGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        SlideShow ok = new SlideShow();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Methods that create and show a GUI should be run from an event-dispatching
         * thread
         */
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that your image array can be any size, you won't need to change any code apart from the array.